# How to re-render information in a modal in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to get my data to re-render in a comments modal after making a post request using Angular. Presently if I close the modal by hand and then re-open it by hand it will display the updated comment in my modal, however I would much rather have this happen live when I press the submit button.

Presently this is what my modal what I have been using to no success.

```
<div class='comment-content' *ngFor="let comments of data.comments"> 
                  <p class ='comment.user'> {{this.comments.user}}: </p>
                  <p class='comment-body'>{{this.comments.body}}</p>
                </div> 
                <!-- This sets up the comment data to submit -->
                <form (ngSubmit)="datasrv.postComment(data.tono, commentbody.value, data.branch)" (ngSubmit)='handleData()' (ngSubmit)="modalRef?.hide()"
                (ngSubmit)='openModal(template, data)' >
                    <div>
                      <textarea id='submit-body' name='commentbody' value='body' #commentbody></textarea>
                      <button class='submit-button'type='submit' value="submit">send</button> 
                    </div>
```

Is there anyway I can refresh just the modal to get the updated comments from data.comments on submit?

Edit for clarification:

Here is what the top of the modal looks like. There's about 250 lines of modal so I can't share the whole thing. But here are the relevant bits.

```
<ng-template #template>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{data.tono}}</h4>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef?.hide()">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class='tabs'>
              <!--Tabs-->
              <div class="modal-subject-container text-center">
                <div class="row" style="height: 89px;">

                  <!--Details tab-->
                  <div class="col-md-4 modal-category implemented" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; padding: 0px;" (click)="changeModal('details')" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': modalHeaderStyles.details['background-color']}">
                    <div style="height: 70px;display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                      <p [ngStyle]="{'text-decoration': modalHeaderStyles.details['text-decoration']}">Details</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!--Comments tab-->
                  <div class="col-md-4 modal-category" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;" (click)="changeModal('comments')" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': modalHeaderStyles.comments['background-color']}">
                    <div style="height: 70px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                      <p [ngStyle]="{'text-decoration': modalHeaderStyles.comments['text-decoration']}">Comments</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!--Activity tab-->
                  <div class="col-md-4 modal-category" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;" (click)="changeModal('activity')" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': modalHeaderStyles.activity['background-color']}">
                    <p [ngStyle]="{'text-decoration': modalHeaderStyles.activity['text-decoration']}">Activity</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: where is the modal content?

Comment: use behavior subjects that will update data in realtime without refreshing modal